# Extension of Euler's Theorem for Homogeneous Functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

We know that [Euler's Theorem for Homogeneous Functions](http://people.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/EulerHomogeneity.pdf) states that for homogeneous functions of order k:
$f\left ( \bar{x} \right )=\frac{1}{k}\sum_i x_i\frac{\partial f\left ( \bar{x} \right ) }{\partial x_i} $

I was wondering if the above could be extended for the case where $x_i$ itself is a vector. Could we write the above as:
$f\left ( \bar{x} \right )=\frac{1}{k}\sum_i\sum_j x_{i}^{j}\frac{\partial f\left ( \bar{x} \right ) }{\partial x_{i}^{j}}$

Where
$x_{i}^{j}$ is the jth constituent of $\bar{x_i}$
It seems intuitively correct, and I was able to do it for an elementary homogeneous function, but am unable to prove it mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each $x_i$ is a vector (say in $\mathbb R^n$) for $i = 1,\ldots,m$, then $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_m)$ can be thought of as an $m \times n$ matrix, or equivalently an element of $\mathbb R^{m \times n};$ and the functions $x_i^j$ (for $(i,j)\in\{1\,\ldots,m\}\times\{1,\ldots,n\}$) are just the Cartesian coordinate functions of $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$.

Assuming the scalar multiplication you're using in the definition of homogeneity is just componentwise (i.e. $(kx)_i^j = k(x_i^j)$), we see that your second equation is just the standard Euler's theorem for a function defined on $\mathbb R^{m \times n}.$

Comment: Thanks. This seems to have put me on the correct path. I just need to figure out the proof of Euler's Theorem for homogeneous functions of matrices. Any links on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: On second thought, I think I have the proof. It involves implementing the multi-variable chain rule for functions of matrices ($\frac{\mathrm{d}f\left ( \lambda X \right ) }{\mathrm{d} \lambda }= \sum_{i} \sum_{j} \frac{\partial f\left ( \lambda X \right )}{\partial \lambda x_{ij}}\frac{\mathrm{d} \lambda x_{ij}}{\mathrm{d} \lambda}$). Please let me know if you think this is it.

Comment: @AmritPrasad: the point of my answer is that you don't need a different proof - matrices can be thought of as big vectors, so if you have the theorem for vectors then you have it for matrices. If you want to write a separate proof, then yes, it will use the chain rule.